# Unable to lookup sp connection metadata

Tags: saml-2.0, pingfederate

all the configuration tested are correct but still getting this error:

sourceid.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to lookup sp connection metadata for entityid="SP URL"

Comment: You've provided very little data... The version of PingFederate is most important.

Comment: version is 8.0 and I have provided below details:
the setting from Ping are 
connection ID: abc.xyz.com 
Assertion Consumer URL: thisisspurl.com 
The settings from SP side are Issuer: abc.xyz.com Id[ SSO URL: pingurl/idp/SSO.saml2?
PartnerSpId=abc.xyz.com ACS URL: thisisspurl.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the FULL URL as captured inside the quotes for "SP URL" as a VSID for the connection. This usually means that Entity ID for the partner has not been set to what they are sending (which is the SP URL).

This can be avoided by making the SP provide you with metadata, and you build the connection around it, then export your own metadata, and send to them. If they can't provide you with metadata, then they should get better at SAML.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Comment: the setting from Ping are
        connection ID: abc.xyz.com
        Assertion Consumer URL: https://thisisspurl.com

The settings from SP side are
       Issuer: abc.xyz.com
       Id[ SSO URL: https://pingurl/idp/SSO.saml2?PartnerSpId=abc.xyz.com
       ACS URL: https://thisisspurl.com